# Sencha touch one store instance for multiple stores

Tags: storage, sencha-touch, extjs

So I have two stores that use the exact same model, they are exactly the same in every way (except for their names of course). I want two different stores.

```
app.stores.newsFeed = new Ext.data.Store({
   model: 'app.models.feedData',
   proxy: {
      type: 'scripttag',
      url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',
      extraParams: {
        format: 'json'
    },
    reader: {
        root: 'query.results.item'
    }
  } 
});

app.stores.eventsFeed = new Ext.data.Store({
   model: 'app.models.feedData',
   proxy: {
      type: 'scripttag',
      url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',
      extraParams: {
        format: 'json'
    },
    reader: {
        root: 'query.results.item'
    }
}
});
```

My question is can I save space by getting rid of code and use only one store instance so I don't have to re-declare another new Ext.data.Store again?

something like:

```
store = new Ext.data.Store(...);
app.stores.newsFeed = store;
app.stores.eventsFeed = store;
```

I tried this before but both were assigned to the same store so when one was changed so was the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just extend extJS component and you can get fast instances of your component:

```
MyStore = Ext.extend(Ext.data.Store, {
    constructor : function(config) {
        config = Ext.apply({
            model: 'app.models.feedData',
            proxy: {
                type: 'scripttag',
                url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',
                extraParams: {
                     format: 'json'
                },
                reader: {
                     root: 'query.results.item'
                }
            } 
        }, config);                 
        MyStore.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
    }, 

    onDestroy : function(config) {
        MyStore.superclass.onDestroy.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

And create as much independent instanses as you want:

```
app.stores.newsFeed = Ext.create(MyStore, {});
app.stores.eventsFeed = Ext.create(MyStore, {});
```

Comment: this was exactly what I needed thank you. However I couldnt get the Ext.Create to work correctly for me (if kept wanting me to register an xtype). I used app.stores.newsFeed = new MyStore() and it works like a charm.